# does optimization using JIT happens only once and remain forever or just during the lifecycle of the run?

Tags: java, compilation, jit, .class-file

I was reading different articles on `Just-in-time compilers` and it is mentioned that `JIT` optimizes code fragments (hotspots) into direct native code (machine code). My question is
does this optimization happens every time I run the `.class file`. On the otherhand,  traditional `compiled` codes is optimized once and for-ever, not just during one `execution` (for example).

and where does this kind of `hot-spot optimization` "remembered" in the `machine`?

Comment: The JIT can optimise the code based on how it is used.  When this assumption turns out to be incorrect e.g. due to a change in usage, the code can be re-compiled.

Comment: Just In Time as it runs, it's not impossible to do that optimization once ahead of time though: http://www.extremetech.com/computing/170677-android-art-google-finally-moves-to-replace-dalvik-to-boost-performance-and-battery-life

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That could depend on the JRE implementation, but in general JIT optimization gets redone each time you launch the program. Among other things, hotspot environments may *change* their optimization based on runtime profiling with the input data actually being processed.

Yes, this is very different from traditionally compiled languages.

One thing to watch out for: Partly because it depends on input, there is no guarantee that a hotspot JIT will optimize the code the same way every time. This makes trying to hand-optimize Java code MUCH more difficult. You really need to do full profile analysis, and you need to do it over extended executions and a complete range of input data, or you're likely to fool yourself. I've seen 20% performance variation on the same machine running the same code over the same input, apparently because the JIT optimized in a different order and ran into limits on how much native code it was willing to produce.

Comment: More often it is the local *inlining budget* that prevents further optimizations, and it is difficult to decide where to start inlining.

Comment: Ah. I don't know the internals of the JIT well enough -- I know some of the issues, but not all. And having fought to improve performance on large Java apps, that variability in JIT results has driven me utterly bonkers more than once.  I'm tremendously impressed that the JIT works well enough to make Java a viable serious language, but it's still something of a dancing bear.

Comment: By today's standards Java is an easy target. Try optimizing JavaScript :) but they still do it quite well.

Answer (score 2):

The JIT compiler produces artifacts which exist only in the working memory of the JVM process. Even within the same process the same code is often recompiled due to one optimistic assumption or other having been invalidated.

Take note that JIT-compilation can be (and on the HotSpot, *is*) more aggressive than static compilation—mostly due to the above-mentioned optimistic assumptions, which statically compiled code cannot afford.

Comment: what you mean by JIT-compilation can be more aggressive than static compilation?

Comment: I mean it can optimize based on *aggressively optimistic* assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

The [Just-In-Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) translation exists only during the run of the program. When the program terminates the JIT instructions are gone (but they may be regenerated during the next execution - it depends on the "hot" path).